# filter with multiple values of same properties of an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have an object called `tasks`. It has various properties. Now I want to display only the tasks which's status is `to-do` and `in-progress`. Please help me how can I apply the filter in `ng-repeat`.

```
$scope.tasks = [
 {
   'title': 'task one',
   'status': 'to-do'
 },

 {
   'title': 'task two',
   'status': 'in-progress'
 },

 {
   'title': 'task three',
   'status': 'completed'
 }

]

<div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <h1>{{task.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{task.status}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify a custom function to the filter.
here's a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KvyTqnK4Y2ZxeH8uBsYO?p=preview)

code:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:status">
    <h1>{{task.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{task.status}}</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
$scope.status = function(item) {
  if (item.status == 'to-do' || item.status == 'in-progress') return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter: filteredTasks">
    <h1>{{task.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{task.status}}</p>
</div>
```

Create the filter:

```
$scope.filteredTasks = function(task) {
  return (task.status === 'to-do' || task.status === 'in-progress') ? true: false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Avijit. It works for me. Actually I was thinking in different way. But this is the better way. Happy coding :-)